# Trying to understand $\sup$ and $\limsup$ of a sequence.

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

The following is the sequence and a problem that I am working on.

> $\{x_n\} = (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n} + 2\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$
>
> Find the $\sup$, $\inf$, $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of this sequence.

Writing out the sequence, I noticed that because of the trig part, there were 4 main subsequences that tells me that $\{1,-3\}$ are the limit points where three of the main subsequences all go to $1$.

The first term gave me the largest term $2$, so that is the $\sup$.

It seemed like there was no inf because the decreasing subsequence goes to $-3$ but there was not term less than that.

So this is my summary:

$$\sup x_n = 2, \inf x_n = \varnothing, \limsup x_n = 1, \liminf x_n = -3 $$

I am a dilettante in analysis and I feel like I'm starting to get it... but I need to confirm if I'm doing this right.

Any comments?

Note: the sequence was edited so the problem is different.

Comment: Be careful: if you take the subsequence of all the even indexes $\;n\;$ , you get a sequence that converges to $\;2\;$ (In fact, it's a constant sequence)

Comment: Because there is cycling forever, the sup and limsup are the same, as are the inf and liminf.

Comment: The sup is the least value which is greater than or equal to any value achieved in the set/by the function (roughly the same thing); if it is actually attained, then it is the max; else, it can be things like a (horizontal) upper asymptote or what would have been the max if there is a single point of discontinuity at all such values.

Comment: Meanwhile, the limsup is what you get if you 'cut off' the left end/tail of the function/set and then find the supremum of everything on the right - and then repeat this successively as the cutting point travels rightward to infinity. If you look at only disjoint unit intervals which cover the space and find the sup in each of them, then the limit of the sequence of such sups is the limsup. It is a really neat concept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is fine. We say precisely the same thing below.

Look first at the sum of the first and third terms. We start at $n=1$. The first terms go $-1,1,-1, 1,\dots$, cycling with period $2$. The third terms go $2,0,-2,0,2,\dots$, cycling with period $4$.

So their sum goes $1,1,-3,1, 1,1,-3,1,\dots,$ cycling with period $4$.

When we add the middle term, we get
$$1+1,1+\frac{1}{2}, -3+\frac{1}{3}, 1+\frac{1}{4}, 1+\frac{1}{5}, 1+\frac{1}{6}, -3+\frac{1}{7}, \dots.$$

The big guy is easy to pick out, it is the first term $2$. There is no littlest.

The biggest number $a$ which has an infinite subsequence that has $a$ as a limit is $1$, and the smallest number $b$ which has an infinite subsequence that has $b$ as a limit is $-3$.

Comment: Wow ! never thought of it that way, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sin\frac{n\pi}2=\begin{cases}\;\;0&,\;\;n=0,2\bmod 4\\{}\\\;\;1&,\;\;n=1\bmod 4\\{}\\\!\!-1&,\;\;n=3\bmod 4\end{cases}$$

and from here

$$(-1)^n+1+2\sin\frac{n\pi}2=\begin{cases}\;\;2&,\;\;n=0,1,2\bmod 4\\{}\\\!\!-2&,\;\;n=3\bmod 4\end{cases}$$

Since the above cover all the possibilities for an index $\,n\,$ , the set of partial limits simply is $\;\{-2\,,\,2\}\;$

Comment: I also get a $-2$.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I typed the problem wrong, the middle term is equal to \frac{1}{n}

Comment: Thanks Andre...anyway, the problem's been edited and now's different.

Comment: @hyg17, when it takes soooo long to discover a mistake in a question perhaps the decent thing to do is to post *another* question....though I think the answer above can easily lead you to deduce by yourself the new sequence's solution.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for the advice. I was working on another problem in the mean time and lost track of time :(